# Python: tkinter for loop, looping through without caring if my entry field is filled?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

```
k = [1,3]
listBasket = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]

def cont(self, listBasket, k, userID):
    for t in range(len(k)):
        upInfo = Entry(self)
        upInfo.pack()
        updateButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Update", command=lambda: updateListBasket(self, userID, listBasket, t, upInfo.get(), k))
        updateButton.pack()   

def updateListBasket(self, userID, listBasket, t, upInfo, k):
    listBasket[t][2] = (upInfo)
    cont(self, listBasket, k, userID)
```

For some reason my code just goes through the for loop without caring if the value is entered in my upInfo or not. So my updateListBasket recieves the 2nd position of k(value 3); this leads to the updatelist only able to update the element at the 3rd position of the list and not the 2nd

Comment: So my updateListBasket updates the 4th element of k(last element); this leads to the updatelist only able to update the element at the 3rd position of the list and not been able to update the 1st position

Comment: Have you done any research? there are many questions and answers on this site related to creating buttons in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Update this line...

```
updateButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Update", command=lambda: updateListBasket(self, userID, listBasket, t, upInfo.get(), k))
```

To this...

```
updateButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Update", command=lambda t=t: updateListBasket(self, userID, listBasket, t, upInfo.get(), k))
```

And try again.

This essentially tells the anonymous function to use the value of `t` as it is at call rather than as it is after the loop is finished.